# Devise user logout not working on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, devise

i am designing iPhone views for my Rails app, i use the devise gem to authentications, but when i logout in the iphone view, it doesn't work, i ckecked the log, i found this:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-05 17:06:24 +0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

i know the `GET` is where the problem is, but when i test in my desktop browsers, like Chrome and Safari, the logout action is through `DELETE` method:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-05 17:14:58 +0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
```

here is my routes config:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => :show
```

and the logout link:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

i just wondering **why the logout link does't work on Mobile Safari**?

thx a lot.

Comment: this problem solved: i am not include the jquery and jquery_ujs, and the jquery_ujs tends for support "make non-GET requests from hyperlinks".

Answer (score 1):

Probably Mobile Safari doesn't support RESTful design, so it can't send Delete HTTP request.

Try matching a route in your routes.rb file as a Delete HTTP request

```
match "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :via => [:delete]
```

Then, your link for sign out should be like this

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', logout_path %>
```

If it doesn't work, try overriding the Devise::SessionsController like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 def log_out
  #custom log_out
 end
end
```

And then add the route in your routes.rb file to that action as a get HTTP request.

I partially tested those and worked for me. Let me know if you get solved, because I have not fully tested those solutions.

If you need more information about RESTful designs you should look at this:

http://www.slideshare.net/calamitas/restful-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery and jquery_ujs.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>
```